# How to run python function by clicking html button?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to make this web app to work but I am getting an error. these are the steps that web app is supposed to handle:

1. import a file
2. run the python script
3. export the results

when I run python script independently( without interfering with flask), it works fine( I use Jupyter notebook) on the other hand, when I run it with flask (from prompt) I get an error:

```
File "app.py", line 88, in <module>
    for name, df in transformed_dict.items():
NameError: name 'transformed_dict' is not defined
```

Any idea of how can I make this web app to work?
This is my first time using flask and I will appreciate any suggestions or guidance.

[python file & html file](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/nhsi6bym1mls3tq/AABc0hs1BvFcl2UwUEfwynFea?dl=0)

```
from flask import Flask,render_template,request,send_file
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import os
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import sqlalchemy as db

def transform(df):
    # Some data processing here 
    return df

app=Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('firstpage.html')


@app.route('/upload',methods=['Get','POST'])
def upload():
    file=request.files['inputfile']

    xls=pd.ExcelFile(file)

    name_dict = {}

    snames = xls.sheet_names

    for sn in snames:
        name_dict[sn] = xls.parse(sn)

    for key, value in name_dict.items():
        transform(value)
    transformed_dict={}

    for key, value in name_dict.items():
        transformed_dict[key]=transform(value)

#### wirte to excel example:
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("MyData.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')
for name, df in transformed_dict.items():
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=name)
writer.save()

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(port=5000)
```

Comment: You just need to indent the last block so that it's run as part of `upload()`

Comment: @Randy thank you for your answer. Can you please show me an example? I am not sure if I  understand your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Your block:

```
#### wirte to excel example:
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("MyData.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')
for name, df in transformed_dict.items():
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=name)
writer.save()
```

should be part of your `upload()` function since that's where you define and fill `transformed_dict`. You just need to match the indentation there to the block above it.

The current error is coming up because it's trying to run that code as soon as you start your script, and `transformed_dict` doesn't exist at that point.

Comment: thank you for help. I was able to run the script without any error but I am not sure why nothing happens when I click the "submit" button. What am I missing here?